# Create form in Rails for multiple instances of has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `hotel.rb` which have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :rates` and `has_many :rates` relationship.

I want create a form for when I create a new Hotel **could create multiple instances of Rates**.

This code works good but only for single instance or Rate in `_form.html.erb` in hotel views.

```
<%= fields_for :rates do |rf| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= rf.label :stock %>
      <%= rf.number_field :stock, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= rf.label :service %>
      <%= rf.text_area :service, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

How think in add multiple instances is adding multiple fields like an array:

```
<%= rf.number_field 'rates[stock][]', class: 'form-control' %>
```

But then I must program the create of all instances in controller from params.

Comment: I think you can see this since it's little bit long explanation in SS, http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments

Comment: Cocoon is a good gem to look at, allows you to add multiple instances of a related object in a nested form. This post does a good job walking you through the process of setting it up, https://www.sitepoint.com/better-nested-attributes-in-rails-with-the-cocoon-gem/